# Rotate PDF without truncating contents using PDFsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, rotation, pdfsharp, portrait

After rotating to portrait view, how might I ensure all content is visible (within page bounds)?

PDFsharp truncates my page when rotated by +90 degrees but not when rotated by -90 degrees.

```
PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument();
XPdfForm old = XPdfForm.FromFile(in_filename);
PdfPage newP = outputDocument.AddPage();

if (old.Page.Orientation == PageOrientation.Landscape)
{
    old.Page.Rotate= (old.Page.Rotate - 90) % 360;
    old.Page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
}

newP.Height = old.Page.Height;
newP.Width = old.Page.Width;

// Get a graphics object for page1
XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(newP);

// Draw the page identified by the page number like an image
gfx.DrawImage(old, new XRect(0, 0, old.PointWidth, old.PointHeight));
```

The above works for a few pdf test cases, but I am skeptical it is coincidental/luck

I am using PDFsharp 1.50 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known problem with PDFsharp 1.50 **beta** with respect to importing rotated PDFs. That problem is still under investigation.

PDF files come in many different variations, therefore it is very difficult to ensure that code works in all cases.

Comment: thanks. Much to my chagrin, I ended up not being able to reliably scale pdfs using PDFsharp or PDFclown. I ended up using itextsharp: http://shihamsamsudeen.blogspot.com/2010/06/itextsharp-read-existing-pdf-resize-it.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following:
(Note, this only had to work for a landscape to portrait)

```
        var output = new PdfDocument();
        var outputPage = output.AddPage();            

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(pdfBase64String)))
        {
            using (var input = XPdfForm.FromStream(stream))
            {
                outputPage.Height = input.PointWidth;
                outputPage.Width = input.PointHeight;

                using (var graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(outputPage))
                {
                    graphics.RotateAtTransform(90, new XPoint(input.PointHeight / 2, input.PointHeight / 2));
                    graphics.DrawImage(input, new XRect(0, 0, input.PointWidth, input.PointHeight));

                }

            }
        }
```